# rosed for read-only files

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm a newbie- and I was trying to use the "rosed" command to edit one of the .cpp source files that came in the package image_view.

However when I follow the instructions here:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/UsingRosEd

after I make the change I cant save it-- it says:
"/opt/ros/electric/stacks/image_pipeline/image_view/src/nodes/extract_images.cpp" E212: Can't open file for writing

How do I change the permissions? Obviously "sudo" won't help.

Any help is highly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37764/rosed-for-read-only-files/) by [rps2689](https://answers.ros.org/users/2743/rps2689/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-07-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should not edit files in /opt/ros since they by system packages. Instead, create an overlay. Have a look at the [rosws tutorial](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/rosinstall/html/rosws_tutorial.html) and [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/36784/how-to-install-a-stack-and-package-manually-in/).

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3